# How to understand noise growth in BFV?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, lwe, ring-lwe, error-propagation

I am trying to understand the noise growth due to multiplication in BFV encryption.

As explained in section 4 and equation 3 of this paper: https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/144.pdf.

I couldn't follow what is $r_a$ and $r_r$ is in their equations.

Also how they are bounding the values of all rounding errors?

Also is there are simpler explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\boldsymbol{r}_a$ is the approximation error for Equation 3, since we are creating an approximation where we round the ciphertext values.

$\boldsymbol{r}_r$ are the non-integer values in the equality generated by scaling Equation 2 by $t/q$, i.e.: $$\textbf{r}_r=\frac{t}{q}\cdot[\textbf{v}_1\cdot\textbf{v}_2]_\Delta-\frac{r_t(q)}{q}\cdot (\Delta\cdot \textbf{m}_1\cdot\textbf{m}_2+(\textbf{m}_1\cdot\textbf{v}_2+\textbf{m}_2\cdot\textbf{v}_1)+\textbf{r}_v$$ Note that these will be the only values affected by the rounding. The error from this rounding is bounded by $\lVert r_r\rVert$ (since $[\boldsymbol{r}_r]_q=\sum_{i=0}{[r_{r_i}]_q\cdot x^i})$

As for a simpler explanation I've yet to find one, if you only need the implementation and not the correctness perhaps consider [this site.](https://inferati.com/blog/fhe-schemes-bfv)